# Como fazer efeito slide com jquery e js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom, utilizando jquery e js, eu queria fazer um slide onde meu php iria puxar muitas divs, e o limite será de 8 divs, por exemplo, se clicar no botão next, irá avançar para outras divs que não cabem na página, e se clicar no botão prev, vai voltar. Como posso fazer isso?

http://prntscr.com/7yktnp

HTML:

```
<div class="noticias">
<div class="box">Título</div>
</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
```

Comment: esse efeito é chamado de *carousel* ou *slideshow* [esse exemplo do Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) é bem fácil de adaptar

Comment: Já deu para ter uma base, muito obrigado.

Comment: Em http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp se ensina como fazer um carousel, bem detalhadamente. No caso, é usado bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

O nome desse efeito se chama `Slideshow`: Como exemplo, tem o modelo do **bootstrap**. Para funcionar é preciso inserir o arquivo css e o js da versão que pretende utilizar.

Aqui tem um modelo funcionando: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Você também pode fazer o efeito manualmente a partir de um efeito de transição do jQuery, o que requer mais trabalho e conhecimento, como também pode utilizar um plugin como esse o jQuery Cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Há muitos outros *plugins* que permitem fazer esse efeito. Faça uma pesquisa no google pelas palavras: **Carousel, Slideshow, slidebox, slide gallery, slider** que terá alguns exemplos, tem alguns que são pagos e outros gratuitos, não esqueça de ler os termos de uso. Recomendo analisar também o suporte para as versões mobiles, pois alguns deles não fluem com o movimentos *touchs*. Boa sorte.